# Create variables with conditional logic from dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column called 'success' (amongst others). It this column, we have only 0 and 1 values. Now, I want to count how many times each value occurs.

I tried this command: `sdf.groupby('success').sum()` but it only gives me a table with the unique counts in 1 view. 
[image]

Since I need to do math on the individual frequencies of 0 and 1, I need it in 2 variables, thus seperatly. Exmaple:

```
col1=6100
col2=5878

c=col1/(col1+col2)
```

How to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please review [ask] and create a [mcve], that includes a sample input and desired output.

Comment: @user3483203 sorry for that, i hope i corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `value_counts` to count how many times each value in a column occurs. Then you could turn the resulting series into a dataframe, and transpose it to get the values as column headers.

```py
counts = pd.DataFrame(sdf['success'].value_counts()).transpose()
```

Let me know if this works for you.

To do your calculation, you can then try to apply a `lambda` function to your resulting dataframe (which I named `counts`). `row[0]` will access your count of 0s in success since the previous code resulted in a column called 0.

```py
counts['result'] = counts.apply(lambda row: row[0]/(row[0] + row[1]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you but when I run your 2 lines, it does not return anything:

Comment: When you say it doesn't return anything do you mean that there is an error? Or that nothing is printed to the console?
If there is no error, try `print(counts)` after running the first line.